# Finding a specific conditional format rule

Tags: vba, excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I'm hoping someone can see the problem, I cant. Thank you

Here is what I have tried..

`TargetRange` = the cell range to check

`Formulacell` = the interior.color of the rule, stored when the rule is created by another sub

I reasoned that if I use a unique color for the background I could use that value to find the rule and then delete it. however when I run the code below it often deletes another rule instead. I want ot be able to find and remove a rule with out disturbing the global formatconditions rules. I can do it manually, but that's not the point. I need vba coding to do it so it can be automated.

```
 For I = 1 To TargetSheet.Range(TargetRange).FormatConditions.Count
   If TargetSheet.Range(TargetRange).FormatConditions(I).Interior.Color = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Leave").Range(FormulaCell).Value Then
      TargetSheet.Range(TargetRange).FormatConditions(I).Delete
      Exit For
   End If
 Next I
```

Comment: record a macro, then modify the resulting code

Comment: Can't make macros here, lol Ill try that when I get home. thanks

Comment: When deleting things from a collection it's usually best to loop backwards.

Comment: I am confused. If you have used conditional formatting surely it is a global rule by definition. You may have specified the range it applies to. When you modify that range in its application by definition you are modifying the global rule, no? I feel like i am missing something here.

Comment: Thanks to all who replied.

Comment: It seem that the Line .delete method after an Index Reference is not consistent, But if you create a variable as formatcondidtion and use that reference to delete the conditional format.

          Set FCObject = TargetSheet.Range(TargetRange).FormatConditions(I)

          FCObject.Delete